# AlertDialog Onclick

Tags: java, android, xml

If I have an alertdialog, and I have two buttons, "OK" and "cancel", where the alertdialog only consists of a editText field, how can I create it so that "OK" will only allow the user to continue if the input is not null?

For instance, if input is null and the user presses "OK", it will prompt a toast but wont cancel the alert dialog?  I'm having the issue now where if the input is null and they press "OK", the alertdialog closes.

Comment: Post the code of your onClick() method of OK press handler.

Answer (score 1):

For an `AlertDialog` with an `EditText` you'll have to create and `AlertDialog` with a **Custom View**. The `Ok` and `Cancel` then will just be the logic.

For this I have to create a custom layout file:

Custom Layout XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#AEAAEE"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="#9A9A9F"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Please input character"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="17sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edittext"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="input" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/cancelButton"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Cancel"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/okbutton"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="OK"
            android:textColor="#FFF" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Your Custom Layout Java File:

```
public class CustomDialog extends Dialog implements android.view.View.OnClickListener{

      public Activity c;
      public Dialog d;
      public Button cancelButton, okButton;
      public EditText input;

      public CustomDialog(Activity a) {
        super(a);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.c = a;
      }

      @Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog);
        okButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.okbutton);
        input = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext);
        cancelButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.cancelButton);
        okButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        cancelButton.setOnClickListener(this);

      }

      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.okbutton:
            String value = input.getText().toString();
            if(value.length()<0){
                Toast.makeText(c.getApplicationContext(), "No input", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            break;
        case R.id.cancelButton:
            dismiss();
            break;
        default:
        break;
        }
        dismiss();
      }

}
```

On reference:

```
CustomDialog dialog = new CustomDialog(activity);
dialog.show();
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to make a custom alert dialog for this.
Please look at this example [Android Prompt User Input Dialog Example](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-prompt-user-input-dialog-example/). If the input is null or a blankspace `""` dont cancel the alert Simple.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily achieve this by reading about [Dialog](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html). Here is a tutorial about [Android Custom Dialog](http://www.learn2crack.com/2013/11/android-custom-dialog-example.html).

Answer (score 1):

Use Android Custom Dialog. And for both button and edittext use below code.

**Code :**

```
alertDialogBuilder
                        .setCancelable(false)
                        .setPositiveButton("OK",
                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                            int id) {
                                        // get user input and set it to result
                                        // edit text
                                        if (editext.length() == 0) {
                                            Toast t = Toast
                                                    .makeText(
                                                            getApplicationContext(),
                                                            "write something in edittext",
                                                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                                            t.show();
                                        } else {
                                            Toast.makeText(
                                                    getApplicationContext(),
                                                    "You clicked on OK",
                                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                            dialog.cancel();
                                        }
                                    }
                                })
                        .setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                            int id) {
                                        dialog.cancel();
                                    }
                                });

                // create alert dialog
                AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

                // show it
                alertDialog.show();

            }

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

on the OK button's onclicklistener,

```
if (editext.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty())
//show toast
else 
//proceed
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any way to handle this short of making a subclass of AlertDialog and handling the input logic manually. Alternatively, you could check the value in the EditText and display another dialog with the error message?
Or you could try disabling the button until such point as the input in the EditText is valid by setting a Listener on the EditText.

Though all these options are really just work around for what should be a simple custom Dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
    Activity temp = this;
```

& now in ur code use

```
 AlertDialog.Builder nointernetconnection = new AlertDialog.Builder(
        temp);
nointernetconnection
        .setIcon(R.drawable.logo)
        .setTitle("No Internet Connection")
        .setMessage(
                "You don't have an internet connection...")
        .setCancelable(true)
        .setPositiveButton("OK",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg,
                            int arg1) {
                        //finish();
                        }
                });
AlertDialog a = nointernetconnection.create();
a.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

It is much simple. This is how i did:

create your `prompts.xml`:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/layout_root"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="10dp" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Enter Backup Name: "
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editTextDialogUserInput"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <requestFocus />

</EditText>

</LinearLayout>
```

Then,

inside `onClick()` of your view:

```
    LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    View promptsView = li.inflate(R.layout.prompts, null);

    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    alertDialogBuilder.setView(promptsView);

    final EditText userInput = (EditText) promptsView.findViewById(R.id.editTextDialogUserInput);

    // alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(false); //optional

    alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                                                    {
                                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id)
                                                        {
                                                            if(userInput.getText()+"" != "")
                                                            {
                                                                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,AskForTextFile.class);
                                                                i.putExtra("userInput",userInput.getText()+"");
                                                                startActivity(i);
                                                            }
                                                            else
                                                            {
                                                                Toast.makeText(context, "Please enter backup name to go further.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                                            }

                                                        }
                                                    }
                                        );

    alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                                                        {
                                                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id)
                                                            {
                                                                dialog.cancel();
                                                            }
                                                        }
                                        );

    AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
    alertDialog.show();
```